# Terraform's azurerm_lb_rule doesn't assign frontend and backend ports in Azure Portal

Tags: azure, terraform, azureportal, azure-load-balancer

I'm trying to assign some frontend and backend ports for an Azure load balancer using Terraform's `azurerm_lb_rule` resource but it is not picking up values.

```
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "test" {
  name     = "testLoadBalancerRG"
  location = "West US"
}

resource "azurerm_public_ip" "test" {
  name                         = "testPublicIPForLB"
  location                     = "West US"
  resource_group_name          = "${azurerm_resource_group.test.name}"
  public_ip_address_allocation = "static"
}

resource "azurerm_lb" "test" {
  name                = "TestLoadBalancer"
  location            = "West US"
  resource_group_name = "${azurerm_resource_group.test.name}"

  frontend_ip_configuration {
    name                 = "PublicIPAddress"
    public_ip_address_id = "${azurerm_public_ip.test.id}"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_lb_rule" "test" {
  resource_group_name            = "${azurerm_resource_group.test.name}"
  loadbalancer_id                = "${azurerm_lb.test.id}"
  name                           = "LBRule"
  protocol                       = "Tcp"
  frontend_port                  = 3389
  backend_port                   = 3389
  frontend_ip_configuration_name = "PublicIPAddress"
}
```

When I try to create a load balancer with the `azurerm_lb_rule` resource I am unable to see frontend and backend port associated with port in the Azure portal

[image: Azure portal screenshot after applying Terraform configuration]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here's whats working for me:

```
variable "ports" {
  "default" = [2379, 6443]
}

resource "azurerm_lb" "lb" {
  name                = "${var.reference["name"]}-${var.vmName}-lb"
  location            = "${var.reference["location"]}"
  resource_group_name = "${var.reference["name"]}"
  count               = "${var.vmName != "worker" ? 1 : 0}"

  frontend_ip_configuration {
    name      = "private"
    subnet_id = "${var.hack}"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_lb_backend_address_pool" "lb-backend" {
  resource_group_name = "${var.reference["name"]}"
  loadbalancer_id     = "${azurerm_lb.lb.id}"
  name                = "backend"
  count               = "${var.vmName != "worker" ? 1 : 0}"
}

resource "azurerm_network_interface" "nic" {
  name                = "${var.reference["name"]}-${var.vmName}-vm-${count.index}-nic"
  location            = "${var.reference["location"]}"
  resource_group_name = "${var.reference["name"]}"
  count               = "${var.reference["${var.vmName}Count"]}"

  depends_on = ["azurerm_lb.lb"]

  ip_configuration {
    name                          = "dflt"
    subnet_id                     = "${var.hack}"
    private_ip_address_allocation = "dynamic"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_network_interface_backend_address_pool_association" "nic-lb-backend" {
  network_interface_id    = "${element(azurerm_network_interface.nic.*.id, count.index)}"
  ip_configuration_name   = "dflt"
  backend_address_pool_id = "${var.vmName != "worker" ? azurerm_lb_backend_address_pool.lb-backend.id : ""}"
  count                   = "${var.vmName != "worker" ? var.reference["${var.vmName}Count"] : 0}"

  depends_on = ["azurerm_network_interface.nic"]
}

resource "azurerm_lb_probe" "probe" {
  resource_group_name = "${var.reference["name"]}"
  loadbalancer_id     = "${azurerm_lb.lb.id}"
  name                = "${element(var.ports, count.index)}"
  port                = "${element(var.ports, count.index)}"
  count               = "${var.vmName != "worker" ? length(var.ports) : 0}"
}

resource "azurerm_lb_rule" "rule" {
  resource_group_name            = "${var.reference["name"]}"
  loadbalancer_id                = "${azurerm_lb.lb.id}"
  name                           = "${element(var.ports, count.index)}"
  protocol                       = "Tcp"
  frontend_port                  = "${element(var.ports, count.index)}"
  backend_port                   = "${element(var.ports, count.index)}"
  frontend_ip_configuration_name = "private"
  backend_address_pool_id        = "${var.vmName != "worker" ? azurerm_lb_backend_address_pool.lb-backend.id : ""}"
  probe_id                       = "${var.vmName != "worker" ? element(azurerm_lb_probe.probe.*.id, count.index) : ""}"
  count                          = "${var.vmName != "worker" ? length(var.ports) : 0}"
}
```

reference variable:

```
variable reference {
  default = {
    "name"         = "k9s"
    "location"     = "ukwest"
    "addressSpace" = "10.240.0.0/22"
    "etcdCount"    = 3
    "masterCount"  = 3
    "workerCount"  = 3
  }
}
```

Comment: example explained in my question is standard example available in terraform documentation. i dont want to create nic, vm ...but just one which is present in my example. https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/loadbalancer_rule.html

Comment: i think you need a probe and a backend for this to work, it wont work without those

Comment: yes after adding azurerm_lb_backend_address_pool i can able to see port numbers are able to associate. thanks for your input

Comment: The important thing in my case was to make the `azurerm_lb_probe` `name` field dynamic/unique by e.g. appending the rule's port number to it.